# Pass data to a varaible with pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I connected to a database and there are some datas in it.

In here I print the name of the person whose id is 2

```
cursor.execute('Select Name from Customers Where Id = 2')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

The name of the person is "Alex" it this code is being printed like this

```
('Alex', )
```

I want to pass this name "Alex" to a varaible and then when i print it I want it to be look like

```
print(name)
```

answer

```
Alex
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(row[0])
```

It is a tuple, so extract so first element from it.